# Inequality - Logarithm of the Sum of Exponentials

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

Is it true that for $0<\alpha<1$ and $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n\in\mathbb{R}$ we have the inequality:

$$
\log \sum_{i=1}^n e^{\alpha x_i+(1-\alpha) y_i} \leq \alpha\, \log \sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i}+(1-\alpha) \, \log \sum_{i=1}^n e^{y_i}
$$

The furthest I could prove is that

$$
\log \sum_{i=1}^n e^{\alpha x_i+(1-\alpha) y_i} \leq \alpha\, \log \sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i}+(1-\alpha) \, \log \sum_{i=1}^n e^{y_i} + \log n
$$

Comment: $1-\alpha y_i$ or $(1-\alpha)y_i$ ?

Comment: $(1-\alpha)y_i$ - my apologies for the typo

Comment: This relation expresses the convexity.

Comment: Correct. I want to prove whether the function 
$$
f(\underline{u}) = \log \sum_{i=1}^n e^{\langle \underline{u}, \underline{x}_i\rangle - \lambda_i}
$$
is convex where $\underline{u}\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $\underline{x}_1, \underline{x}_2, \dots, \underline{x}_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You can show that the epigraph has a convex conic representation https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/expo.html#log-sum-exp Well, if you look there it is even easier, you just have to know that $e^x$ is convex.